# Changing object's value with using set-get methods

Tags: java, oop, get, set

```
public Location stairUp(Location oldLocation,Room newRoom){ // This is from my stair class
    Location newLocation=new Location(newRoom,Game.selectedHero, Game.selectedHero.getLevel(), newRoom.getFloor());
    setOldLocation(newLocation);
    return oldLocation;
}
```

I want to change the user's location by using this method. I have the Location class and its constructor as you can see. But I cannot assign a new location. It doesn't work old location stays. Basically, my question is how can I assign new object instead of old object with using parameter for old object?

---

```
//Rooms
Room room1=new Room(1,1,monster16,stair);
Room room2=new Room(2,2,monster15_Assassin,stair);
Location location=new Location(room1,Game.selectedHero,selectedHero.getLevel(), room1.getFloor());
System.out.println("---------------old---------------");
location.displayLoc(selectedHero);
stair.stairUp(location,room2);
System.out.println("-----------new---------");
location.displayLoc(selectedHero);
```

This is the main part that I am using the object. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

If the old location stays the same, there are two possibilities,

- You're not change really assigning the new location object's address
  to the old location object
- You're still using the old location's    object.

The problem is either on setOldLocation() or on the usage part of the old location object.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the return stairUp method, I am not sure why oldLocation is returned from the method. You should be aware that "oldLocation" returned from this method is the local variable passed to this method

`public Location stairUp(Location **oldLocation**,Room newRoom)`

This is always going to point to the old value of location that was passed to the method.

Comment: even if I don't use return, and use void instead of return ,it is still not changing.

Comment: Try making these changes to the method and call

``
  public Location stairUp(Location oldLocation,Room newRoom){ 
      // This is from my stair class
      return new Location(newRoom,Game.selectedHero, Game.selectedHero.getLevel(), newRoom.getFloor());
  }

  .......
  location = stair.stairUp(location,room2);
  System.out.println("-----------new---------");
  location.displayLoc(selectedHero);

``